# Deleting an array of Class Objects

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am having some problems with memory leaks and I can't seem to find a way to patch them. Characters is a class data member of type Sprite*. Sprite is a class inherited from the class Image2D. And objects is an array of Image2D objects which holds all the possible sprites to choose from.

```
class Sprite :
public Image2D
    {
    private:
        char * name;
        int left, top;
    }

Sprite::~Sprite()
    {
        delete[] name;
    }

class Image2D
    {
    private:
        ConsoleColor fg, bg;
        char *text;
        unsigned short width, height;
    }

Image2D::~Image2D()
    {
        delete[] text;
    }

Class Game
    {
    private:
        Sprite* Characters;
    }
Image2D * objects = new Image2D[size];
//fill up objects by reading from file.


Characters = new Sprite[2];
int choice1, choice2;
cout << "\n\nWhich sprite would you like to be?  (1, 2, or 3)  ";
cin >> choice1;

Characters[0] = *(new Sprite(objects[choice1].GetFG(), objects[choice1].GetBG(), objects[choice1].GetText(), "Player", 10, 10));

cout << "\n\nWhich sprite would you like your opponet to be? (1, 2, or 3) ";
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
cin >> choice2;

Characters[1] = *(new Sprite(objects[choice2].GetFG(), objects[choice2].GetBG(), objects[choice2].GetText(), "Computer", 70, 10));
delete[] objects;
```

Here is my destructor for the Game Class...

```
~Game() {
        delete[] Characters;
        }
```

The leaks are coming from Characters and specifically when I assign Characters[0] and Characters[1] but I'm unsure as how to patch them.

SOLUTION:
Change...

```
Characters[0] = *(new Sprite(objects[choice1].GetFG(), objects[choice1].GetBG(), objects[choice1].GetText(), "Player", 10, 10));
```

to

```
Characters[0] = Sprite(objects[choice1].GetFG(), objects[choice1].GetBG(), objects[choice1].GetText(), "Player", 10, 10);
```

and same for Characters[1].

Comment: I don't see the code where you actually allocate the arrays... And also why use `char *` for the name instead of `std::string` to avoid having to do manual memory management? Really likewise for `text` in `Image2D` if it represents actual text. If you need compatibility with `C` code you can always call `string.c_str()` when passing to the `C` function.

Comment: My c++ is a bit rusty but i think when you `delete[] Characters` you only delete the `characters` its memory and not the memory each character uses for its `char * name`

Comment: You'd be right if the Characters array was an array of pointers, but if it's an array of instances I believe their destructor is called.

Comment: Cannot use string due to class limitations. Have to use char *. Also, I posted some more code and where I initialized the arrays. Characters IS an array of pointers.

Comment: you are missing ; at the end of the class declarations

Comment: No, it's not. See my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one reason:

```
Characters = new Sprite[2]
```

allocates two `Sprite` instances using their default constructor.

However, you then overwrite those instances in:

```
Characters[0] = *(new Sprite(objects[choice1].GetFG(), objects[choice1].GetBG(), objects[choice1].GetText(), "Player", 10, 10));
```

What this is doing is a shallow copy of the data in `Sprite`, meaning its pointer to the `name` string is being re-assigned to point to the location in the newly allocated object, but the original is never freed. So when you call `delete[]`, the stuff you allocated manually is indeed freed, but the original default allocations are not.

You should make it:

```
 Characters = *Sprite[2]
```

and:

```
Characters[0] = new Sprite(objects[choice1].GetFG(), objects[choice1].GetBG(), objects[choice1].GetText(), "Player", 10, 10);
```

Or inside the copy-constructor/`operator=` in `Sprite` you need to make sure you free any held memory before re-assigning the `name`/`text` pointers.

Oh, and it also never looks like you free the `Image2D` array allocation you did, and are likely having the same leak with that array as well.

Comment: If I make Characters = Sprite*[2] I get an error type not allowed. I do have a copy constructor where I do a deep copy using memcpy as opposed to shallow. The objects array is freed, just didn't include that code, it's in there now.

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should be `* Sprite[2]`

Comment: Fixed it! When I assign Characters[0] and [1] I don't need to call new, I can just set it equal to the constructor of a sprite and it will overwrite what I previously had. Mem leaks are all gone now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your base classes destructor is not virtual. Which means your derived classes destructor is not being called => memory leak.

Comment: The base class destructor was virtual, but I've found the problem now. Thanks for your insight c: